# Video encoder for java on Raspi

Tags: java, video, raspberry-pi

I need java h.264 encoder which allow me to create a video made of buffered images and it must work on Raspbery pi. JCodec is too slow for me.

Comment: I have code which sends the raw data of images from webcam and i need something to compress it into h264. So i think showing a code isn't necessary.

Comment: What happens if you google search for a Raspberry PI compatible h.264 encoder? Doesn't FFmpeg work with PI? Do you think it's possible your settings/hardware is causing slowness instead of JCodec itself?

Comment: @VC.One I think JCodec is too slow itself especially in live stream encoding because it's pure java lib and doesn't use hardware acceleration.
FFmpeg works with pi but i couldn't find a way to encode sequence of image from memory to buffer.

Comment: In Java I only know how to send raw RGB data (bitmaps) to command line FFmpeg.exe (Windows) for encoding. I assume you use FFmpeg API library as imported into your Java classes? Check online how an application can provide its FFmpeg API instance with bitmap data (24bit RGB).